# getting output to display as percentage in python

Tags: python

I am pretty much designing simple code that determines a students grade as P (>65%) or NP from the total of 5 given tests. This is the code I have designed for it so far, based on how my professor wants it and I would like to have the results of total correct be displayed as a percentage but I have been having trouble finding the right way to code this.

```
# Initialize Variables
studentName = "no name"
test1 = 0
test2 = 0
test3 = 0
test4 = 0
test5 = 0
totalScore = 0
finalGrade = 0
gradeMessage = None

# Print report title
print("\n Isabelle S - Programming Problem Two")

# Get user input data
studentName = input("Enter name of student ")
test1 = int(input("Enter test score 1: "))
test2 = int(input("Enter test score 2: "))
test3 = int(input("Enter test score 3: "))
test4 = int(input("Enter test score 4: "))
test5 = int(input("Enter test score 5: "))



# Compute values
totalScore = test1 +test2 +test3 + test4 + test5
finalGrade = totalScore / 100 * 100.0
if finalGrade >65:
 gradeMessage = "P"
else:
 gradeMessage = "NP"

# Print detail lines
print("\n Name of student: " , studentName )
print("Total Correct: " , totalScore )
print("Final Grade: " , gradeMessage )
```

Comment: If the maximum score is 100, then `totalScore` is already the desired percentage.

Comment: Take a look at the [python format specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec) or [here](https://pyformat.info/). Also, I can't see where you output `finalGrade`

Comment: `totalScore / 100 * 100` doesn't make any sense. Do you mean to do `(totalScore/5) * 100`? You could literally do `print("Total Correct: " , str(totalScore) +'%' )` if your question is how to add a percent sign

Comment: Dear Isabelle, I hope you found the answers given below to be helpful. Please accept one of the many answers given if you found them useful. =)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the percentage, you need to divide by the *maximum total score*, then multiply that by 100 to get percent.

```
numberOfTests = 5
pointsPerTest = 100
finalGrade = totalScore/(numberOfTests*pointsPerTest) * 100

# Formatting like this allows all sorts of neat tricks, but for now
# it just lets us put that '%' sign after the number.
print("Final Grade percentage: {}%".format(finalGrade))
```

Answer (score 0):

Isabelle, one needs to know what are the **maximum possible points** in each test (`test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4` and `test5`). Assuming that the maximum possible points in each of these tests is **100**, one can change your code slightly. Instead of `finalGrade = totalScore / 100 * 100.0`, you can use `finalGrade = totalScore / 5`.

Following is the complete code (with the aforementioned change). =)

```
from __future__ import division

# Initialize Variables
studentName = "no name"
test1 = 0
test2 = 0
test3 = 0
test4 = 0
test5 = 0
totalScore = 0
finalGrade = 0
gradeMessage = None

# Print report title
print("\n Isabelle Shankar - Programming Problem Two")

# Get user input data
studentName = input("Enter name of student ")
test1 = int(input("Enter test score 1: "))
test2 = int(input("Enter test score 2: "))
test3 = int(input("Enter test score 3: "))
test4 = int(input("Enter test score 4: "))
test5 = int(input("Enter test score 5: "))

# Compute values
totalScore = test1 +test2 +test3 + test4 + test5
finalGrade = totalScore / 5
print finalGrade
if finalGrade >65:
 gradeMessage = "P"
else:
 gradeMessage = "NP"

# Print detail lines
print("\n Name of student: " , studentName )
print("Total Correct: " , totalScore )
print("Final Grade: " , gradeMessage )
```